# A numerical analysis problem

Tags: numerical-methods

I was looking at old exam papers and was stuck on the following problem:

[image]

I have hardly any idea how to progress with the problem. Can some give some explanation about how to progress with the problem?

Comment: Is the question to choose which of the numbers 1-4 is a correct statement?

Comment: @learner: Hint: Look at the condition number of A.

Comment: I think options 1,2 correct.Am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what "large" and "small" mean precisely here, but I would imagine that this is getting at the operator norm. Given a matrix $A$, there is the operator norm $\|A\|$ which satisfies $$\|Ax \| \leq \|A\|\|x\|$$ for any $x$. In the language of the question, we have the equation $$\|r\| = \|A(x - x_c)\| = \|Ae\| \leq \|A\|\|e\|.$$ If we push the vector $r$ to zero, what happens to $e$, given this inequality? If we push $e$ to zero, what happens to $r$?

Comment: From  your calculation it appears to me (1) is the correct choice as if I push $e \to 0 \implies r \to 0.$ Am I right? But here,more than one options is possible.Can other options be a possibility?  I also think option 2 is possible whereas 3 is not possible..option 4 is clearly false. So,1,2 are correct.Anything wrong?

Comment: 3 and 4 don't seem correct. 2 does. For instance, if $A(x,y) = x-y$, then there are arbitrarily large errors that will be sent to zero!

Comment: Thanks for your opinion...So correct options are 1,2.